# How to extract part of a string between 2 delimiters, in Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a variable length string starting with START and ending with END as delimiters.

I want to extract the string between `START` and `END`.
I tried doing

```
SET _result=%String:~6,-4%
ECHO %_result%
```

Its removing the first 5 characters but not the last 3 characters as I want.

Suppose, `_result=STARTblahblahblahEND`
I am getting the output as `blahblahblahEND`

What I want is:

```
blahblahblah
```

Comment: take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36630524/extract-content-between-2-strings

Answer (score 0):

You could use the substring options. Would something like the below work?

```
SET TEXT=STARTblahblahblahEND
SET SUBSTRING=%TEXT:~5,-3%
echo %SUBSTRING%
```

Comment: Or switch to PowerShell ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should work unless the target string is multiline:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "str="
set "string=blablablaSTART123ENDblablabla"

set string=!string:START=^

!
set string=!string:END=^

!

FOR /F skip^=1eol^= %%S in ("!string!") do if NOT DEFINED str set "str=%%S"
echo(!str!
```

---

How does it work?

```
^
%= EXPANDS TO NOTHING =%
%= EXPANDS TO NOTHING =%
```

expands to a single `LF`.

`skip^=1eol^=` disables `eol`